# What is the appropriate way of getting file attributes in C on Windows?

Tags: c, windows

I would like to get file attributes in C on cross platform. I tried `stat` and `access`, they both work fine on Unix-like systems (Ubuntu, Mac OS X). But this commands misbehave on Windows, for example: whether there is read permission for file or not, `stat` and `access` both always return true.

Here is my function, which works correctly on Unix-like systems.

```c
int is_readable(char *file)
{
    struct stat fileStat;
    stat(file, &fileStat);
    return (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR);
}
```

What is the right way of getting file attributes in C on Windows (cross platform solution would be even better)?

Comment: Is the `S_IRUSR` macro from MinGW? I would expect the POSIX definition of `S_IRUSR` to always be true on Windows if the file can be listed via [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418). That's because the C runtime doesn't check the file's security descriptor discretionary access control list (DACL). It only checks the file attributes available in a [`WIN32_FIND_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365740) record.

Answer (score 2):

File permissions on unix like systems and windows are completely different.
So I think, the easiest is simply try reading the file and deal with the errno/return code.

Comment: This will probably work for checking `read` permission, but I think it is not possible to check for `write` permission.

Comment: @user3140972: sure it is; open the file for writing.  If that succeeds, you have write permission (well, on Windows, anyway; I would assume Linux behaves the same way).  On Windows, it isn't feasible to determine ahead of time whether you'll be able to open a file or not, because there are too many different reasons why you might not be able to.  The only approach that will work is to handle the error that occurs when you try and fail to open the file.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, overwriting a file will fail (access denied) if the hidden/system attribute is set and the new file isn't created with the same attribute. Unix-centric programs often create `.files` directly in a user's profile. If the user hides the file, the program needs to first get the attributes of the existing file to pass to `CreateFile` or use `ReplaceFile`. I've seen such programs annoyingly rename and create a new file without copying the existing attributes. So, while rare, I do think there are valid reasons to LBYL, and the C standard library isn't always enough.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, how can you open a file only for writing without overwriting? In Unix-like systems mode `w`will overwrite, and mode `w+` opens file not only for writing, but also for reading - which means if there is no read permission an error will be returned.

Comment: @user3140972: sounds like you're still trying to figure out whether you can write to the file or not ahead of time - the idea is to wait until you *actually want* to write to the file.  You *can* check your access rights ahead of time using CreateFile() if you want but all that tells you is what you can do *now*, not what you'll be able to do later.

Answer (score 1):

On Win32, `access()` really should work. I suspect you used it wrong, it returns 0 on success. [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy.aspx) is pretty clear:

> Each function returns 0 if the file has the given mode. The function returns –1 if the named file does not exist or does not have the given mode; [...]

It's easy to incorrectly interpret `-1` as `true`; you must compare against `0`.

Also, I would argue that your function doesn't work correctly, it doesn't handle the case when `stat()` fails. I/O is brittle, you must error-check!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that it returns 0 on success. I will try the example in provided link. But last time I tried a similar example on Win64, it did not work correctly.

Comment: Microsoft's implementation of access() doesn't check the file ACLs, only whether or not the target is a directory and whether or not it has the read-only attribute set.